# Cannot start MySQL Client on Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having trouble getting my MySQL to work. I have found that I have to learn database programming on short notice, so I installed a MySQL server onto my Mac OS sierra system. Now I can't figure out how to start it. Everyone is saying go to terminal and type MySQL, but it just says not found. Is there a specific client software I'm supposed to be using? Thanks all.

Comment: How did you install MySQL in your machine? Can you read the documentation of the installation source?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a virtual machine instead of mucking with your Mac like that..  Let me recommend scotchbox https://box.scotch.io/ which works instantly out of the box, with mysql all ready and fired up.  Then when you mess up your database you can just wipe the whole thing and start again in a blink.